# How do I un-render a component after routing it to another component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, routes

index.js page:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import NewUpload from './components/newUpload';
import Testing from './components/Testing';
import Landing from './landing/Landing';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render( <Router>
           <Route path='/upload' component={NewUpload} />
           <Route path='/' component={Testing} />
           <Route path='/landing' component={NewUpload} />
       </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Testing.js (this is the first page that loads upon npm start):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Testing extends Component{
render()
{
  return ( <div>
             <form action='/upload'>
               <button type="button">click to upload</button>
             </form>  
           </div>
      )
}
}
```

So when I click on this button, it sure routes me to the new page, but the button is still visible on the new page as well. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `exact` prop to the `Route` component.

```
  <Route exact path='/' component={Testing} />
```

This ensure that the path matches the location.pathname exactly.
See the docs [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool)

Comment: Thanks for the input. It works!
However, I am sending data data through different components, and at the same time I need to route to those pages. How can I achieve that?